# Is it possible to stop HIVE from printing the database when printing column headers using hive -e 'select'?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When performing:

```
hive -e 'select * from database.table' > /localfilesystem/mytable.txt
```

the column header names are in the form `database.columnname` and I would like them to be `columnname` only.  Is there a way to supress the database in the columnname when performing the above type of query?

Comment: Did you try `hive -e 'USE database; select * from table' > ...`.  I'm slightly confused by the question, As I understand the column names in header are `tablename.columnname`. May be you are using a different version of hive.

Comment: We were using hive 0.08 and all we got was calling name without the database. Then we move to 0.13. and now the database is in the name of the column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names` was added in 0.13 and defaults to `True`.  Just set it to `false` in your `~/.hiverc` or in `hive-site.xml`

```
 <property>
   <name>hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
```