# HIVE - Remove database name from heading when exporting to excel

Tags: sql, hive, export-to-excel, heading

I have a table = Table_name,has 3 columns,

Select * from Table_name

Results appear  exactly as below (column headings)

Table_name.Col1 |   Table_name.Col2 |   Table_name.Col3

However, When I export to Excel. Column names are

Table_name.Col1 |   Table_name.Col2 |   Table_name.Col3

Is there away to keep the headings as       Col1    Col2    Col3

New to Hive hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below property before your `select` statement!

```
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false
```

Then hive doesn't printout the `tablename` as part of column names.

Comment: Hi Shu, Thanks for the reply. I wrote the query on Hive as, set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
select * from Table_name;  But i still got the Table_name.col etc... Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure, try this approach... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705985/is-it-possible-to-stop-hive-from-printing-the-database-when-printing-column-head, change in `hive-site.xml` and `restart hive` service..

Comment: Thanks Shu, Your  "set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false"   Didnt work for me because I didnt   "restart hive"  I just did that and works like a charm now. Thanks so much